Representing growth in learning outcomes
The average score of my class of students at the beginning of the year was 50/100 and at the end of the year, it was 80/100.
The percentage growth is 60%.
Can I write there is 1.6x growth in average scores? Or is it 0.6x growth in average scores?
Is there anyway I can phrase the growth in a way that allows me to use 1.6x?

Honestly, it's just 4 numbers, you can't beat just reporting those.
That said, you might also say:

Scores were $1.6\times$ better
Scores improved by $30$ percentage points
Scores improved by $60\%$ (percent)

Still, I would end all of those sentences with "... from $50$ to $80\%$," to avoid any confusion over the meaning.
